# What's the difference between suit, lawsuit, litigation, accusation, proceeding?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

These words *suit*, *lawsuit*, *litigation*, *accusation*, *proceeding*, when translated into my native language they are all the same. I also have looked them up in the dictionaries and it seems they are very very similar. Could someone help to explain the differences between them please?

I reflected on these words and trying to give my understanding about them. For me, *suit* is exactly the same as *lawsuit* (*suit* has other means for sure). *litigation* seems have the same meaning as *suit* or *lawsuit*. Like in *that galvanized her interest in women rights litigations*, I believe we can also say *that galvanized her interest in women rights lawsuits*. *proceeding* seems like the arguing processing in the court to discuss who is right and who is wrong. I only use *proceeding* in the usage *criminal proceeding*. *accusation* is like a claim saying someone did something wrong.

Is my understanding accurate? Please help to correct me.

Comment: 'Suit' (in this context) is merely an abbreviation of 'lawsuit'.

Comment: A [law]suit is a particular legal case, while _litigation_ refers to legal proceedings in general.  You are correct about _accusation_.